# Unexpected result with cblas_dgemv

Tags: c++, c, blas, intel-mkl

I have a question regarding cblas_dgemv. I am trying to understand how it works. And what I am possibly doing wrong. I have an array Matrix and then I try to read that matrix RowMajor and ColumnMajor.

I am getting the expected result in the RowMajor Case; [6, 2, 4, 6]'.

However for the ColMajor, I am getting [-7, 3, 0, 5]' when the answer should be [6, 3, 2, 3]'

Here is my code. I am using Intel MKL.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <mkl.h>


#define NCols 5
#define Nrows 4

double A[] = { 8, 4, 7, 3, 5, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 0, 1, 1 , 2, 3, 4, 1};

double x[] = { -1, 2, -1, 1, 2 };

double y[Nrows];
double alpha = 1.0, beta = 0.0;
char tbuf[1024];
int main() {
    int i, j;

    // Print original matrix

    // y = Ax
    cblas_dgemv(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, Nrows, NCols, alpha, A, NCols, x, 1, beta, y, 1);
    // Print resulting vector
    for (j = 0; j < Nrows; j++) {
        printf(" %f\n", y[j]);
    }

    cblas_dgemv(CblasColMajor, CblasNoTrans, Nrows, NCols, alpha, A, NCols, x, 1, beta, y, 1);
    // Print resulting vector
    for (j = 0; j < Nrows; j++) {
        printf(" %f\n", y[j]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is on the `lda`. From the reference we get that

> lda: The size of the first dimension of matrix A

The `CblasRowMajor` and `CblasColMajor` describe the memory storage sequence of a two dimensional matrix.

The `CblasRowMajor` storage of a matrix `A(nrow,ncol)` means that first are stored the `ncol` values of the first row of matrix `A`, then the `ncol` values of second row of `A` and so on.

The `CblasColMajor` storage of a matrix `A(nrow,ncol)` means that first are stored the `nrow` values of the first column of matrix `A`, then the `nrow` values of second column of `A` and so on.

So in `CblasRowMajor` storage the LDA *(first dimension of matrix A)* is the `ncol` while in `CblasColMajor` the `nrow`.

In your example you just have to change `lda` of the second `cblas_dgemv`

```
cblas_dgemv(CblasColMajor, CblasNoTrans, Nrows, NCols, alpha, A, Nrows, x, 1, beta, y, 1);
```