# openblas sgemv CblasRowMajor implementation returns wrong results (cblas_sgemv)

Tags: openblas, cblas

I did some test using `cblas_sgemv` in openblas and found that it returned a wrong result in my test case.

```
A is
1 2
3 4
5 6

B is 
1 2
```

The output C should be `5 11 17`

But, it outputs `5 14 0`

Here is the sample code.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/15mCkfcQuruQxi4CjvVkoK2jfgnG2w3izd0wMFMW6UOk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

the lda parameter seems to be wrong. since the order is CblasRowMajor it should be 2 (number of columns) instead of 3 (number of rows).

cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30208420/6058571